# template filter tag in django - filtering {{activate_url}}

Tags: django, reactjs, filtering

I am working with django and react and developing a multi tenant application where each subdomain in django is a different company. Using rest framework. 
At user registration(company wise user) a confirmation email is send to each user to activate their account.

The email send to users are in the format of

***http://company_code.localhost.com:8000/rest-auth/account-confirm-email/key***

subdomain wise. After some search i came to know this goes from allauth, send_confirmation_message.text file and in the form of ***{{activate_url}}***

for activating the account from react what i did was changed the default 'send_confirmation_message.txt' file of allauth as :

'http://localhost:3000/verify-email?key={{key}}' -- react

now i automatically filter my key from url on react and post to backend, and activate the account,
the manual part still is getting company code from the url which django send in the email.

Again i have read about template filter tag but can not use. 
So how can i use filter on {{activate_url}} which is 
***http://company_code.localhost.com:8000/rest-auth/account-confirm-email/key*** 
to get my company_code and send to react in the form of url.

Getting company_code is important as users are company wise and react should post to a specific company.

Or My approach is wrong and should try something other ?

**Thanks**

Comment: I don't understand your question: Is the url in the email incorrect? Where is react involved (what page) and what are you trying to do?

Comment: the url in the email is correct, but i dont want people to click on that. that will take to the rest framework page or say my backend.  all i want is to activate the account from my front end that is react and redirect to login page.

Comment: you can check above url.... company_code is my subdomain... i have different schemas in database for each subdomain. I have already got the value of key in url.. if i get my subdomain also my url in email will look like ***http://frontend.com/verify-email?key=key&company_code=subdomain*** all i need to do is filter {{activate_url}} to get the subdomain. I want to change the link which users recieves. {{activate_url}} is in allauth-> template-> account->email->email_confirmation.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work..

{% blocktrans %} in email_confirmation_message.txt was not allowing me to apply any filer on {{activate_url}} or add any new block.

I removed it and changed the url which user receive in email for activating the account.
The new url is :
`http://front-end.com/verify-email/?id={{key}}&id1={{activate_url|slice:"7:12"}}`
subdomain is always of 5 character,in my case.

and it takes me to my front end, automatically activate the account on componentDidMount and redirect to login.

ps: blocktrans will not allow to apply any filter, add new block. 
still don't know what blocktrans is, if anyone can provide detail.

Thanks